# Why do I need to instantiate an object in C#, but not in C++ in order to access a class's functions?

Tags: c#, c++, memory, memory-management

I have recently began programming in C# for Unity(game engine) development. I noticed that unlike C++; C# requires me to instantiate an object on the heap before using its member functions or variables. Where as with C++ I can declare an object and call any function from the declaration name.

C++ Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class SampleClass 

{
   void PrintFunc()
   {
      cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
   }
 }

int main()
{

   SampleClass objectC; //Object declaration
   objectC.PrintFunc(); //Use of function without instantiation

   //The above code will print'Hello World'
}
```

C# Example:

```
 using System

 namespace ConsoleProject2
{
    class MainClass
   {

   class SampleClass
   {
        Void PrintFunc()
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {

        SampleClass objectC = new SampleClass();
        //Must instantiate before accessing member functions 
        objectC.PrintFunc(); //Prints out 'Hello World'

    }
}
```

}

Reading on Unity's [Automatic Memory Management](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnderstandingAutomaticMemoryManagement.html) website I was only able to conclude that due to it's automatic garbage collection it may require you to place new objects on the heap since it deallocates them for you. (May be a false assumption, please correct me)

Why do these two languages differ when it comes to accessing an objects properties? Is the object in C++ being placed on the stack since there is no instantiation; if so why not place all objects on the stack?

Thank you.

Comment: Because they are different languages, that's all there is too it.

Comment: you're instantiating an object in the c++ code too. Just because you don't explicitly call `new` doesn't mean you're not creating an object. You're making one with *automatic storage duration* in C++, and using the default constructor to do it.

Comment: It is irrelevant that you use unity3d.

Comment: I think the main problem is you are comparing apples (C++ class) to oranges (C# class) - better comparison is C++ class to C# struct and C++ pointer to C# class - each pair behaves very similar (I've tried to make it in answer...).

Comment: @jaggedSpire That is precisely my point. Automatic storage duration places the C++ object on the stack(because rids of it after the function exits); why can't we place a C# object on the stack?

Comment: Seriously dude? C# is a managed language, like Java.  It does not permit Object types to be declared "on the stack", because you could pass a reference to it. If it was then "freed" some way other than by GC, you couldn't have GC in the language.  Don't like it? Write your game in C++. And put your objects on the stack. And pass pointers to them. And crash. Enjoy.

Answer (score 5):

There is a great deal of misinformation on this topic floating around the internet, so read critically.

> I noticed that unlike C++, C# requires me to instantiate an object on the heap before using its member functions or variables.

This is the wrong way to think about it in C#.  Don't think of "new" as "the thing that makes storage on the heap".  Think of "new" as "the thing that invokes a constructor that initializes an object".  Whether that object is passed around by making copies of it (a value type) or accessed by automatically dereferencing a reference to it (a reference type) does not change the fact that *every object needs to be constructed in a manner that ensures it is properly initialized*, regardless of whether it lives in long term or short term storage.

> Is the object in C++ being placed on the stack since there is no instantiation

There is an instantiation, you're just not seeing it because it is not manifest in the code. A default constructor is called for you.

> if so why not place all objects on the stack?

Stop thinking of "the stack" and "the heap" and start thinking of "the short lifetime variables" and "the long lifetime variables".  Why do we not place all objects on the short-term-variable pool?  *Because some objects have long lives*, that's why.

Relax and let the garbage collector do its job. It does a good job!

Answer (score 0):

In the CLR, objects are created on the heap by default.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f144e03t(v=vs.110).aspx

There are ways to create objects on the stack, but generally everything is created on the heap.

In C++, using `new` creates the object on the heap, whereas `Object o;` creates the object on the stack.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366533(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference<sup>*</sup> between C++ and C# in behavior of value types (which what C++ classes are from C# point of view).

Following C# code compiles and run just fine with code identical to C++ version:

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
  SampleClass objectC; // variable declaration, initialized with default of type
  objectC.PrintFunc(); //Use of function of object just initialized
}


struct SampleClass // note: "struct" in C# matches C++ "class"/"struct"
{
     public void PrintFunc()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Reverse is true too: pointers in C++ are rough equivalent of classes in C# and following C++ code not going to work:

```
int main()
{
   SampleClass* objectC; // "SampleClass*" in C++ is equivalent 
                         // of variable of class type in C# 
   objectC->PrintFunc(); //try to use of function without instantiation

   //The above code will NRE
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Languages and platforms are indeed very different, but comparing C# class with C++ class is wrong way to try to apply understanding of concepts in one language to another.

Detailed explanation of heap vs. stack is in real [answer by Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38513543/477420)...

Answer (score -2):

In C++, writing `SomeClass objectName;` invokes the default constructor to initialize the object. In general, there are no uninitialized values of class types in C++.

Comment: "there are no uninitialized values in C++" huh?

Comment: @user4759923 default-initialization for non-class, non-array types causes ["no initialization to be performed"](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#7). (and arrays default-initialize their elements) The result is of *indeterminate value*.

Comment: I clarified my answer